# How can I find the currently playing song in Banshee?

Tags: music, banshee

Is there any way to quickly go to the song currently playing in Banshee? Maybe double-clicking something?

My library is quite large, and scrolling to the currently playing song after I've scrolled several songs down can be challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Under the "Playback" menu, there is an item named "Jump to Playing Song".  Its key-combination is Control+J.