# Banshee - How can I show/highlight the track currently playing in the library for editing?

Tags: banshee

- Banshee 2.6.2 (Xubuntu 14.04)

**How can I use the keyboard to set the focus on the track which is currently playing?**

I sometimes navigate through the program to do something else and then can't get back to the track somehow. This is needed though, e.g. if I want to edit its meta data or do something else wit hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more searching, I found the solution [in another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351695/how-can-i-find-the-currently-playing-song-in-banshee?rq=1):

> Under the "Playback" menu, there is an item named "Jump to Playing Song". Its key-combination is Control+J.

Thanks to Aoeuid.

Note: this only works if the track is still listed in the playlist, i.e. not possible for a "smart" playlist for unplayed tracks.